# Adding domain specific vocabulary to Huggingface pretrained tokenizer

Tags: python, spacy, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

I am using the `hugginface` transformers package and am loading a pretrained `OpenAIGPTTokenizer` tokenizer from a vocab file and merges file.

I want to add some domain-specific words to the vocabulary of this pretrained tokenizer (words such as `"sms"`, `"idk"` and `"lol"`)

When I tokenise a word that is currently in the vocabulary, the resulting token has a `</w>` symbol appended which I assume means end-of-word.

```
>>>tokenizer.tokenize("hello there lol")
["hello</w>", "there</w>", "lo", "l</w>"]
```

However, if I try and add a token to the tokenizer, it doesn't have a `</w>` symbol at the end. Although, at least the tokenizer recognises that `"lol"` is its own token.

```
>>>tokenizer.tokenize("hello there lol")
["hello</w>", "there</w>", "lol"]
```

I don't think this is the correct way to go about extending the vocabulary. What should I do?

Thanks